# XML to tab-separated file

Tags: xml, coldfusion

I have been trying to get XML into a text file as tab-separated file using Coldfusion. I was wondering if anyone can give me some hand in how to approach this.

My XML can be of multiple nodes with multiple child nodes. I can work out the logic of maintaining the count of tabs for each child node and then getting it back to starting point.

Is there any specific recursion algorithm which I don't know about?

The xml is like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Personnel"
id="b02bfa5f-f2d0-45ac-99e0-9e4e12416db1">
<I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Ranks"
    id="c25d4732-862b-4dc4-835e-eb167f63a114">
    <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Army"
        id="7a54176d-38f9-4753-bb93-60649e70ddb1">
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Field Marshall (Fd Marshall) (FM)"
            id="5d311b9d-8d6e-4fa8-8933-a643bf55143d" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="General (Gen)"
            id="56d3aae4-7da9-4940-9692-e1ad90584127" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Lieutenant General (Lt Gen)"
            id="0f1bb73b-39ae-4920-9d23-2c92d543ef37" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Major General (Maj Gen)"
            id="9f269157-fde9-4ea4-ae1e-65344d56388e" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Brigadier (Brig)"
            id="33e15bd2-aa5e-4a99-8096-821568bf7156" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Colonel (Col )"
            id="fa38285d-2319-4e43-9207-3c4080497118" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Lieutenant Colonel (Lt Col) (CO)"
            id="9fab6b6a-c4b1-4b5d-a051-8c22260f3225" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Major (Maj) (OC)"
            id="9c232a00-1e54-427f-9fdf-73aa50f4c49e" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Captain (Capt) (SO3)"
            id="18043ea4-d9cd-41cd-9a5c-851de350b397" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Lieutenant (Lt)"
            id="9dfc1631-e49d-48e7-ad47-7ce41da36cdf" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Second Lieutenant (2nd Lieutenant) (2Lt)"
            id="4f423559-b2a6-4164-8718-b7fce8180331" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Subaltern"
            id="38f33ead-17d3-4358-8fc4-1e03ee46008a" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Cornet (Cnt)"
            id="59ed6193-4e6a-413f-92da-cb37508bc637" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Officer Cadet (Ocdt)"
            id="bfb6ab3a-13e5-46c0-82e7-0d63b794b4f6" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Junior Under Officer (JUO)"
            id="dfe840e8-421a-4017-9066-429e7b3778ed" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Senior Under officer (SUO)"
            id="52f083f3-0826-4b25-be68-3cefd8561e15" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Conductor (Cdtr)"
            id="3ed346d3-0248-40f7-bcfb-ba9b8dabe02f" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Non Commissioned Officer (NCO)"
            id="c0b0af29-f6c6-47f0-8a49-27514d78a55d" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Senior Non Commissioned Officer (SNCO)"
            id="aeaa3bcf-b104-4261-8a5b-652bdd4b8531" />
    </I>
</I>
```

and the tsv file i want shud b like this -

```
Personnel
Ranks               
    Army            
        Field Marshall (Fd Marshall) (FM)       
        General (Gen)       
        Lieutenant General (Lt Gen)     
        Major General (Maj Gen)     
        Brigadier (Brig)        
        Colonel (Col )      
        Lieutenant Colonel (Lt Col) (CO)        
        Major (Maj) (OC)        
        Captain (Capt) (SO3)        
        Lieutenant (Lt)         
        Second Lieutenant (2nd Lieutenant) (2Lt)        
        Subaltern           
        Cornet (Cnt)        
        Officer Cadet (Ocdt)        
        Junior Under Officer (JUO)      
        Senior Under officer (SUO)      
        Conductor (Cdtr)        
        Non Commissioned Officer (NCO)      
            Senior Non Commissioned Officer (SNCO)
```

Comment: FYI, strictly speaking what you're asking for is not for a TSV -formatted file, but rather a report.  TSV would mean your content is in tabular form, with each value in each row in the table separated by tabs (rather than, say, commas).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best bet is to use XSLT:

```
<cfxml variable="myXML">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Personnel"
id="b02bfa5f-f2d0-45ac-99e0-9e4e12416db1">
<I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Ranks"
    id="c25d4732-862b-4dc4-835e-eb167f63a114">
    <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Army"
        id="7a54176d-38f9-4753-bb93-60649e70ddb1">
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Field Marshall (Fd Marshall) (FM)"
            id="5d311b9d-8d6e-4fa8-8933-a643bf55143d" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="General (Gen)"
            id="56d3aae4-7da9-4940-9692-e1ad90584127" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Lieutenant General (Lt Gen)"
            id="0f1bb73b-39ae-4920-9d23-2c92d543ef37" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Major General (Maj Gen)"
            id="9f269157-fde9-4ea4-ae1e-65344d56388e" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Brigadier (Brig)"
            id="33e15bd2-aa5e-4a99-8096-821568bf7156" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Colonel (Col )"
            id="fa38285d-2319-4e43-9207-3c4080497118" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Lieutenant Colonel (Lt Col) (CO)"
            id="9fab6b6a-c4b1-4b5d-a051-8c22260f3225" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Major (Maj) (OC)"
            id="9c232a00-1e54-427f-9fdf-73aa50f4c49e" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Captain (Capt) (SO3)"
            id="18043ea4-d9cd-41cd-9a5c-851de350b397" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Lieutenant (Lt)"
            id="9dfc1631-e49d-48e7-ad47-7ce41da36cdf" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Second Lieutenant (2nd Lieutenant) (2Lt)"
            id="4f423559-b2a6-4164-8718-b7fce8180331" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Subaltern"
            id="38f33ead-17d3-4358-8fc4-1e03ee46008a" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Cornet (Cnt)"
            id="59ed6193-4e6a-413f-92da-cb37508bc637" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Officer Cadet (Ocdt)"
            id="bfb6ab3a-13e5-46c0-82e7-0d63b794b4f6" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Junior Under Officer (JUO)"
            id="dfe840e8-421a-4017-9066-429e7b3778ed" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Senior Under officer (SUO)"
            id="52f083f3-0826-4b25-be68-3cefd8561e15" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Conductor (Cdtr)"
            id="3ed346d3-0248-40f7-bcfb-ba9b8dabe02f" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Non Commissioned Officer (NCO)"
            id="c0b0af29-f6c6-47f0-8a49-27514d78a55d" />
        <I BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS="Senior Non Commissioned Officer (SNCO)"
            id="aeaa3bcf-b104-4261-8a5b-652bdd4b8531" />
    </I>
</I>
</I>
</cfxml>
```

The above stores your XML in a CF XML Object.
Next, the XSLT object:

```
<cfxml variable="myXSLT">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="treeWalk">
      <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="0"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="node" select="I"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="treeWalk">
    <xsl:param name="depth"/>
    <xsl:param name="node" select="0"/>


    <xsl:call-template name="tabs">
      <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$depth"/>
    </xsl:call-template>

    <xsl:value-of select="$node/@BMSMETA_AUTOMETASET_4_OPTIONS" />  
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>

    <xsl:if test="$node/I">
        <xsl:for-each select="$node/I">

            <xsl:call-template name="treeWalk">
              <xsl:with-param name="depth" select="$depth+1"/>
              <xsl:with-param name="node" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:if>   

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template name="tabs">
    <xsl:param name="count"/>

        <xsl:if test="$count > 0">
            <xsl:text>  </xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="tabs">
              <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>   
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
</cfxml>
```

Last, the application of the XLST to the XML:

```
<cfset output = XMLTransform(myXML, myXSLT)>

<cfoutput>
<pre>
#output#
</pre>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: +1, I would give you additional points for effort if I could.

Comment: Great answer, one comment.  If using cfxml isn't an option you could use XMLParse to turn your XML string into a ColdFusion XML object.

Comment: Awesome! and a bit of duh! moment for me. I never thought about the xslt route. I wrote a long recurvive function and webt mad. U  save me a lot of time :)